# Inherit Dart class from a JS class?

Tags: javascript, dart, createjs

I have an HTML5 game made using CreateJS js library. I would like to rewrite it using Dart, but most of my objects inherit from CreateJS objects (e.g. Container). Would I be able to save such inheritance? Is there a nice way of using Dart with other js libraries designed to simplify drawing on canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dart class cannot directly extend a Javascript class. However, you can customize your Javascript object by setting method that will execute Dart code.

For instance, let suppose you have a `Child` Javascript class that extends `Container` class :

```js
function Container(){}
Container.prototype.callSayHello = function(){ this.sayHello(); }
Container.prototype.sayHello = function(){ alert("hello from JS"); }

function Child(){}
Child.prototype = new Container();
```

On Dart side you can create a `Child` and define a `sayHello` method on it overriding `sayHello` from `Container` :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:js/js.dart' as js;

main(){
  // with sayHello overriding
  js.scoped((){
    final child = new js.Proxy(js.context.Child);
    child.sayHello = new js.Callback.many(() {
      window.alert("hello from Dart");
    });
    child.callSayHello(); // displays "hello from Dart"
  });

  // without sayHello overriding
  js.scoped((){
    final child = new js.Proxy(js.context.Child);
    child.callSayHello(); // displays "hello from JS"
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it will probably help me out.

Comment: This answer seems very outdated (as of Dart 2.1)... could you please add an update explaining how to do this with the more recent versions of Dart?